# Installed C++ with VS Build Tools, but can't find CL.exe

Tags: c++, jenkins-pipeline, build-tools

We have a Jenkins build agent based on `docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8`

Part of the Docker file for the container pulls in additional workloads as follows

```
vs_buildtools.exe --quiet --wait --norestart --nocache modify \
--installPath "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools" \
--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VCTools \
--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.DataBuildTools \
--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.UniversalBuildTools
```

But builds of C++ projects fail saying they can't find CL.EXE.

I've Googled this problem and everybody who's had errors saying they couldn't find CL.EXE got the answer to just run `vsvars.bat` and that fixed it for them.  But the CL.exe ***is physically not there***.  We go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103 and there is no bin folder.
We searched the whole container for cl.exe and do see it in some c:\windows\WinSxS\ folder, and we tried adding that to the PATH environment, but it got an error about it not being compatible with the version of Windows.

Is there some reason it won't install the actual compiler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to pass either `--includeRecommended` or `--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64` as an argument.

*MSVC v143 - VS 2022 C++ x64/x86 build tools (Latest)* is listed among
[Components included by VCTools workload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-build-tools?view=vs-2022#desktop-development-with-c) as **Recommended**
and thus is not installed with *Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VCTools* by default.

Here's the description of the `--add` parameter from [VS Installer command-line parameter reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/use-command-line-parameters-to-install-visual-studio?view=vs-2022#install-update-modify-repair-uninstall-and-export-commands-and-command-line-parameters):

> During an install or modify command, this repeatable parameter
> specifies one or more workload or component IDs to add.
> The required components of the artifact are installed, but not the
> recommended or optional components. You can control additional
> components globally using `--includeRecommended` and/or
> `--includeOptional` parameters.

Comment: We rebuilt the container with --includeRecommended and that solved that problem.